# Путь к php-скрипту из компонента Angular

Tags: php, angular

Имеется компонент (Angular 2) с абсолютным адресом php-скрипта:

```
sendApiURL: string = 'http://localhost/myApplication/API/rxURL.php'
```

В результате билда получаем папку dist, располагаемую в папке public на хостинге, а php-скрипт отправляется в папку app, следовательно нарушается исходная файловая структура.
Как правильно указать путь к скрипту?

Answer (score 0):

После билда Angular приложения

```
ng build --prod
```

в папке назначения (обычно dist) в файле index.html указана точка входа:

```
<base href="/">
```

От нее и будут считаться все пути к сторонним файлам.
То есть перед билдом надо менять абсолютный адрес php-скриптов на относительный, что выглядит не очень правильным. Если кто-то подскажет, как сделать это правильно, буду очень признателен.